# How to use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response object to download files?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to download files from google storage through their api and when I'm passing the alt=media parameter I get a response like below:

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)#72 (6) {
  ["reasonPhrase":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["statusCode":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  int(200)
  ["headers":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  array(16) {
    ["x-guploader-uploadid"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(98) "AEnB2Uq5d_aKFnzd6d_DeJ_5P8vi9BiXOJpOzixs7mqU5_WK9SF0o9D-8vQiOQWLw"
    }
    ["content-type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(24) "application/octet-stream"
    }
    ["content-disposition"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "attachment"
    }
    ["etag"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "CODI1+sCEAE="
    }
    ["vary"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Origin"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "X-Origin"
    }
    ["x-goog-generation"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "1458812108000"
    }
    ["x-goog-hash"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(44) "crc32c=D0rU4U+yXOR8d0GKmxkDw=="
    }
    ["x-goog-metageneration"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["cache-control"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(46) "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    }
    ["pragma"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "no-cache"
    }
    ["expires"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
    }
    ["date"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Fri, 25 Mar 2016 09:50:35 GMT"
    }
    ["content-length"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "52"
    }
    ["server"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "UploadServer"
    }
    ["alternate-protocol"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "443:quic,p=1"
    }
    ["alt-svc"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(49) "quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="31,30,29,28,27,26,25""
    }
  }
  ["headerLines":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  array(16) {
    ["X-GUploader-UploadID"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(98) "AEnB2Uq5d_aKFnzd6d6PxQgxGQwE_8S3CYBrhdsiTcOActigXrv_DeJ_5P8vi9BiXOJpOzixs7mqvQiOQWLw"
    }
    ["Content-Type"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(24) "application/octet-stream"
    }
    ["Content-Disposition"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "attachment"
    }
    ["ETag"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "CODI1+6O2csCEAE="
    }
    ["Vary"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "Origin"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "X-Origin"
    }
    ["X-Goog-Generation"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "1458815402108000"
    }
    ["X-Goog-Hash"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(44) "crc32c=D0r0OQ=yXOR8d0GKmxkDw=="
    }
    ["X-Goog-Metageneration"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["Cache-Control"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(46) "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    }
    ["Pragma"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "no-cache"
    }
    ["Expires"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
    }
    ["Date"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(29) "Fri, 25 Mar 2016 09:50:35 GMT"
    }
    ["Content-Length"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "52"
    }
    ["Server"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "UploadServer"
    }
    ["Alternate-Protocol"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "443:quic,p=1"
    }
    ["Alt-Svc"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(49) "quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="31,30,29,28,27,26,25""
    }
  }
  ["protocol":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  string(3) "1.1"
  ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response":private]=>
  object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#57 (7) {
    ["stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    resource(13) of type (stream)
    ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    NULL
    ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    string(10) "php://temp"
    ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

How can I use this to download the file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can download file (pdf, txt, doc) by doing this:

```
$content = $service->files->get($file->id, array( 'alt' => 'media' ));
foreach ($content->getHeaders() as $name => $values) {
    header($name . ': ' . implode(', ', $values));
}
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $yourfilename . '"');
echo $content->getBody();
```

Use the header return from the GuzzleHttp Object.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a working solution!
Note: To force file download (like .mp3 or .mp4) files, change Content-Disposition: inline to Content-Disposition: attachment.

Comment: @Simon it works, one question though. Why does `$service->files->get` return `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response`, instead of returning `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile`, despite it says `@return Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` in phpdoc to `Google_Service_Drive_Resource_Files::get()` method?

Comment: I figured it out. It returns `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response` when you provide `array('alt' => 'media')`. If you omit it, `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` is returned.